# Seperate a list within a table column

Tags: sql-server

I am working on an extremely old database that was created with less than standard specifications and I ran into a problem when aggregating values to create a report. I run into one table where within the columns there are lists. I understand this is "fighting an uphill battle and violating one of the most basic principles of relational database design for no good reason" by having lists within columns but again - it is not my design. I am using a gigantic `UNION` statement to pull from 12+ tables and this one is giving me trouble.

For example, instead of having a `dateSigned`, `datePurchased`, `dateReceived` column in the database, all of these are in one column called `DATE`. This column contains *multiple* values within a delimited list using `|`. The data contained is `||09/19/2011||09/21/2011|||09/23/2011|` with each position being a different date the user input and NULL values being blank. Is there any way within SQL to separate and only use one value from this list? I really want to avoid writing conditions within my view for this particular table to display correctly.

Comment: There are lots of ways.   All of them simple matters of programming.   I recommend you google `SQL Split function`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a split function.

But if you really only want to get one of the values out of the list, and the values are all fixed-width as they appear to be in your sample data, you can simply use SUBSTRING().